# Laravel Validation - Unique Username

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am having problem getting Validation to work properly, currently it is passed when it should not be passed.

Username field (`users.username`) should be unique based on `client_id` in the `users` table. Different client can have same username from other client.

```
$rule['username'] = Rule::unique('users', 'username')->where(function ($query) {
                         $query->where('client_id', $this->user()->client_id);
                   })->ignore($this->user()->id, 'id');
```

For example:

User1 and Users2 are belong to `client_id = 2`

User1 is not allow to change their username to Users2.

Answer (score 0):

Your validation logic works perfectly without any issues. Just make sure you're passing the right user id and client id.

Sample condition

```
DB data
id  username    client_id
1   user1       1
2   user2       1
3   user2       2

Request data by user with id 1 (client_id - 1)
username        validation
user1           pass
user2           fail
user3           pass

Request data by user with id 3 (client_id - 2)
username        validation
user1           pass
user2           pass
user3           pass
```

Sample test code

```
$userId = 1;
$userClientId = 1;

$data = [
    'username' => 'user1',
];

$validator = \Validator::make($data, [
    'username' => Rule::unique('users', 'username')->where(function ($query) use ($userClientId) {
        $query->where('client_id', $userClientId);
    })->ignore($userId)
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    dd('fail');
}

dd('pass');
```